# Wireless internet sharing is mac stuff only

Tags: internet, sharing

I have a Mac G5 and have installed Ubuntu 10.10. It works great except I can't share my internet connection wirelessly with any thing except Mac devices (Itouch and an Ipod).  My touchpad and windows laptop will not even detect my adhoc network. Any Suggestio

Answer (score 1):

WIFI hotspot enables your device to acts like an access point where other device with wirless connectivity can join the particular network and enjoying the surfing. Ubuntu 11.10 gives user easy way to turn their computer into hotspot. You can simply do it without installing any application.
To get started got to the network setting>> Wireless. You will see the following screen in your Computer.

[image: Wifi Hotspot Image]

Click on Use as Hotspot. You hotspot will be immediately create with the SSID name **UBUNTU**. If you want to change it go to configure
[image]

To create your own connection name change your feild in 1. To Enable security in your Hotspot click on 2 as show in above diagram. To change your SSID change your feild in 3. To cloned your MAC address of your device give Mac address in feild 4.
To Configure wireless security, select different security mode of your desire and put your desired password.

[image]

Found More info from [here](http://freshtutorial.com/create-your-own-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-11-10/)